# CheckedListBox datasource not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datasource, checkedlistbox

I have the following code

```
clbCodes.DisplayMember = "Name";
clbCodes.ValueMember = "Id";

checkboxItemList = new List<CheckBoxItem>();
foreach (var uagCode in codes)
{
    var checkboxItem = new CheckBoxItem
        {
            Id = uagCode.Code,
            Name = uagCode.UAGLabel
        };
    checkboxItemList.Add(checkboxItem);
}

clbCodes.DataSource = checkboxItemList;

public class CheckBoxItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I run this, instead of seeing  the "Name" of my item, e.g.,

```
"Card"
"Toy"
"Table"
```

I see

```
WindowsApplication1.CheckBoxItem 
WindowsApplication1.CheckBoxItem 
WindowsApplication1.CheckBoxItem
```

populated in my listbox

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is CheckBoxItem that you are creating a list of?

Comment: DisplayMemberPath = Name after the DataSource line.

Comment: is the clbCodes a Standard ComboBox???

Comment: It's a CheckedListBox

Comment: @PapyrusBit are you sure a CheckedListBox has DataSource Property? I've tried with a CheckedListBox and it doesn't have any property named DataSource?

Comment: Ah, the DataSource is hidden in Intellisense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears that you are adding to the CheckListBox a collection of custom objects, you should have as part of that class an override of `ToString()` that can return the `Name` that you are wanting to display.

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

Comment: What? JeremyK answered this first. Oh my OP, what did you do? It's not fair at all. DonBoitnott, you are so lucky.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override ToString:

```
public class CheckBoxItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
       return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but the DisplayMember seems to useless, so don't need to assign the DisplayMember.

Comment: I think it is because he is using a checkedlistbox instead of a list box, maybe for whatever reason checkedlistbox ignores it